# Write a new line to a file (Python 3)

Tags: python, newline, file-writing

So, after reading many instances of this same question being answered, I'm still stuck. Why is this function not writing on a new line every time?:

```
def addp(wrd,pos):
    with open('/path/to/my/text/file', 'w') as text_file:
        text_file.write('{0} {1}\n'.format(wrd,pos))
```

It would seem as though the `\n` should be doing the trick. Am I missing something?

*I'm running Ubuntu 15.04*

Comment: You are using the wrong mode. You need to use [`'a'` (append)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file-in-python), not `'w'` (write).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be writing newline to the file all the time, the issue maybe that you are openning the file in `w` mode, which causes the file to be overwritten , hence for each call to the above function it completely overwrites the file with just the `wrd,pos` you send in , so the file only contains a single line.

You should try using `a` mode, which is for appending to the file.

```
def addp(wrd,pos):
    with open('/path/to/my/text/file', 'a') as text_file:
        text_file.write('{0} {1}\n'.format(wrd,pos))
```

Comment: Hopefully that was a beginner question, not a dumb one! Thanks :P

Comment: yea, I wouldn't say dumb